Replace icons in Jenkins 2.479.1
The icons are really empty and hurt my eyes and start blending together like crazy after staring at the screen long enough, and I want to replace them with my own using custom CSS.
Only problem is, they seem like they are raw SVGs, and have no CSS name, ID, or anything at all. How do I replace them? There seem to be no plugins that do this.
I tried this with the custom CSS plugin:
.icon-blue, .icon-blue-anime {
    background-image: url('/userContent/custom-blue.png') !important;
    background-size: contain;
}

as well as
but no luck, this doesn't work at all.
Is there a plugin that would do this? I tried a Custom CSS plugin, but a bunch of the SVGs don't even have IDs, and it's a complete mixed bag as to which icons have IDs, Names, or absolutely no discerning information CSS can use.

There doesn't seem to be any actual way to do that with CSS alone. Many Icons in Jenkins don't have any class, and it's a complete mixed bag which do and don't.
One option is to modify the .war file, but this is a pretty poor approach, as you now need to delete the signature and it would also be overwritten.
Another, better option, is to use a combination of JavaScript and CSS.
To do this, you need to install https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin/, and then you can put your CSS AND JS file in $JENKINS_HOME/userContent/
In the JS file, you need to find the image you want to modify and assign a class to the SVG. This is a bit odd, but using querySelector it's quite simple, though you might need to confirm that you don't replace another icon depending on what you selected:
function updateSvgClass()
{
    var stormPath = document.querySelectorAll('path[d="M404.33 152.89H392.2C384.71 84.85 326.14 32 256 32C227.819 31.9729 200.322 40.6756 177.289 56.9116C154.255 73.1476 136.817 96.1198 127.37 122.67H122.8C72.86 122.67 32 163.47 32 213.33C32 263.2 72.86 304 122.8 304H404.33C446 304 480 270 480 228.44C480 186.89 446 152.89 404.33 152.89Z"]');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < storm.length; i++)
    {
        path = stormPath[i];
        svg = path.closest('svg');
        svg.classList.add("icon-storm");
        svg.classList.add("svg-icon");
    }
    //Repeat for the rest of 
}
updateSvgClass();

Some places, like the build side panel, have icons that change on a loop as they update. This will result in the previous change being undone.
One way around this is just to use setInterval:
setInterval(updateSvgClass, 100);

Though not every SVG does this, so you should make sure you don't keep updating ones that don't need to be.
Next, in your custom CSS, you define the icons you want to use, as well as hiding any paths/lines/ellipses/etc:
.svg-icon ellipse,
.svg-icon line,
.svg-icon path {
    display: none !important; /* Hides the ellipse and path elements */
}

.svg-icon{
    background-size: cover;
}

.icon-storm{
    background-image: url(/userContent/images/health-00to19.gif);
}

In this case, a .gif was used, but a .svg should work just as well
